# DBus::Error while running Rails in Ubuntu WSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dbus, wsl-2, networkmanager

I'm using the wsl2 with ubuntu 18.04 and I want to run a [Rails project](https://gitlab.com/glancr/mirros_api) but encountered an error where I can't find the solution.

After starting the Rails application with `rails s` the console prompted me with following error messages.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)
The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files (DBus::Error)
(...)
The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files; caused by 3 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=:1.38 serial=3 reply_serial=3 path=; interface=; member= error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown (DBus::Error)
```

Dbus service is running but I can't get the network-manager to run. Do I even need it? After running `sudo service network-manager restart` and `sudo service network-manager status` I only get  `* NetworkManager is not running`

Looking forward to your replies :)

Comment: This looks like Puma is attempting to use systemd services, but systemd is not supported under WSL at this time.  Whether or not there's a way to run it without these services, I'm not sure.  In my *quick* scan of the Puma docs, it *looks like* systemd is optional.

Comment: Well, Rails itself works just fine with normal projects created with `rails new my_app` :/

Comment: That's to be expected, I would think.  Rails has no dependency on systemd, just Puma.